# OpenCV function does not work same Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, deep-learning

Here is the python code :

```
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame = vs.read()
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0,(300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
    print(blob.shape[2]) # print channel
```

When I try to same code in the c++, the channel value is not same with the python code

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
cv::Mat frame;

while(true)
{
    cap.read(frame);

    Mat blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame,1.0,cv::Size(300,300),Scalar(104.0, 177.0, 123.0));
    cout << blob.channels() << endl; // print channel here
}
```

What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```py
> print(blob.shape[2]) # print channel
> ```

Are you sure that index 2 supposed to contain the number of channels?
In both common 4-dimensional orders, NCHW and NHWC, index 2 of shape does not correspond to channels.